# Creating Multiple subsets from a large dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I am trying to create multiple subsets from a single large data set.

```
UID<-c(1:6)
ID<-rep(UID,times=36)
UConc<-runif(216)
df<-data.frame(ID,UConc)

UID2<-c(1:6)
ID2<-rep(UID,each= 96,times=36)
UConc2<-runif(216*96)
df2<-data.frame(ID2,UConc2)
```

I would like to create 36 subsets from data frame (df and df2) with id's 1-6 each with their respective concentrations. Each ID is repeated but the corresponding concentration is different. 
I tried using Split(x,f,...) which gives the output for each ID (Ex: All ID==1 and respective concentration) but that is not what I want. I want ID 1-6 with respective concentrations and 36 such subsets. Hope this explanation is clear.
Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
split(df, ave(seq_along(df$ID), df$ID, FUN = seq_along))
```

`ave(seq_along(df$ID), df$ID, FUN = seq_along)` will assign a count for the number of times each ID has appeared and when you split, all IDs will be in each group.

To save each group as a separate CSV

```
mylist = split(df, ave(seq_along(df$ID), df$ID, FUN = seq_along))
dir.create("Test_CSVs")
sapply(1:length(mylist), function(i)
    write.csv(x = mylist[i],
              file = paste("Test_CSVs/test_", i, ".csv", sep = ""),
              row.names = FALSE))
```

If there are going to be more than 1 of each ID in each sub-group, try

```
#DATA
UID<-c(1:6)
ID<-rep(UID,each= 96,times=36)
UConc<-runif(216*96)
df<-data.frame(ID,UConc)

N = sum(1 == df$ID)/36
mylist = split(df, ceiling(ave(seq_along(df$ID), df$ID, FUN = seq_along)/N))

#Test
unique(unlist(lapply(mylist, NROW)))
#[1] 576 
#Each sub-group has 576 rows
```

Comment: Seems to be working. Could also tell me how to do write each of these into a CSV file ? That would be great. Thank you.

Comment: 36 different csv's

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks mate. I'll try this out. My df is not this simple coz it has multiple values of conc for each ID. I'll try this out and get back to you in case I run into to some trouble. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Just tried this. The splitting seems to working only when there is only one ID. Observed concentration. Can you tell me how would you approach this data frame..? Thank you.                                          
UID<-c(1:6)
ID<-rep(UID,each= 96,times=36)
UConc<-runif(216*96)
df<-data.frame(ID,UConc)